# Does python's numpy module treats both row vector and column vector in same way?

Tags: python, numpy

I was playing around with numpy matrices to learn more about sub-matrices. Below is the result which I got when I tried to extract a row vector and a column vector:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.zeros(shape=(8,9))
>>> x
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> y = x[:, 0]
>>> y
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
>>> z = x[0, :]
>>> z
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

The thing is that both row vector and column vector are shown in same fashion. So I don't know whether they are treated as same or different.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently fetching only a single row/column from the array, so that's the best way to represent a 1-D view of the row/column returned.

Use **slicing** to get results like this:

```
In [16]: x[:,:1]
Out[16]: 
array([[ 0.],                                                                                    
       [ 0.],                                                                                    
       [ 0.],                                                                                    
       [ 0.],                                                                                    
       [ 0.],                                                                                    
       [ 0.],                                                                                    
       [ 0.],                                                                                    
       [ 0.]])                                                                                   

In [17]: x[:1,:]                                                                                 
Out[17]: array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But I want to know whether they are just printed in the same way or they are also treated as such.

Comment: @PrinceKumar Sorry, I don't understand what do you exactly mean by **treated** here?

Comment: yes, both the row and column slices have the same number of dimensions, and hence the same semantics. there is nothing to distinguish them qualitatively, they are only quantitatively different. note that np.matrix has linear-algebra / matlab style semantics. since numpy tries to be more general than just linear algebra, these default semantics make a lot of sense